# Laravel 4 ajax registering

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4, user-registration

Hello i am using laravel 4 and neon bootsrap theme for a web page, and i cant make the ajax register work please help.

```
        neonRegister.setPercentage(98, function()
                {
               //if i console log here i get the log/
                    var username = $("input#username").val();
                    var password = $("input#password").val();
                    var email = $("input#email").val();
                    var token = $('input[name="_token"]');

                    var dataString = 'username='+ username + '&_token=' + token +'&email=' + email + '&password=' + password  ;

                    // Send data to the server
                    $.ajax({
                        url: baseurl + 'registro',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: dataString,
                        error: function()
                        {
                            alert("An error occoured!");
                        },
               //I never get the success alert or the error alert
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            if(data.status == 'success'){
                                alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
                            }else if(data.status == 'error'){
                                alert("Error on query!");
                            }
                            // Form is fully completed, we update the percentage
                            neonRegister.setPercentage(100);


                            // We will give some time for the animation to finish, then execute the following procedures    
                            setTimeout(function()
                            {
                                // Hide the description title
                                $(".login-page .login-header .description").slideUp();

                                // Hide the register form (steps)
                                neonRegister.$steps.slideUp('normal', function()
                                {
                                    // Remove loging-in state
                                    $(".login-page").removeClass('logging-in');

                                    // Now we show the success message
                                    $(".form-register-success").slideDown('normal');

                                    // You can use the data returned from response variable
                                });

                            }, 1000);
                        }
```

This it´s the javascript it uses, i get a console log at setPercentage(89), but the success or error alert that comes next wont work. U think the error it´s on the ajax but i dont know why.

Here its my controller function :

```
public function store()
{
    $user = new User;

    $user->username = Input::get( 'username' );
    $user->email = Input::get( 'email' );
    $user->password = Input::get( 'password' );


    // Save if valid. Password field will be hashed before save
    $user->save();

    if ( $user->id )
    {
        $response_array['status'] = Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.account_created') . ' ' . Lang::get('confide::confide.alerts.instructions_sent'); 

        // Redirect with success message, You may replace "Lang::get(..." for your custom message.
        echo json_encode($response_array);
    }
    else
    {
        // Get validation errors (see Ardent package)
        $response_array['status'] = $user->errors()->all(':message');

        echo json_encode($response_array);
    }
}
```

I am using zizaco/Confide for the authentication

Comment: Do you see any errors on console ?

Comment: No, the console its 100% clean

Comment: use `dd(json_encode($response_array))` to debug.

Comment: It´s localhost:8000/registro (Its a spanish page) at post method, and dd() doesn't show when using ajax i tried

Comment: i found an error at
    baseurl + 'registro'
change it for:
    baseurl + '/registro'
but now i get a 500 error.

Comment: Is this a resource controller ?

Comment: Show your route declaration.

Comment: Ths one?     `Route::post('registro',                        'UserController@store');`

Comment: Is your token correct ? Can you make a `dd('xxx')` in your method to make sure it works ?

Comment: Use `return Response::json($response_array);` instead of `echo` and make sure `_token` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem it´s something dummy:

at:

```
var token = $('input[name="_token"]');
```

change for:

```
var token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
```

It´s not getting the value of the input so the csrf it´s not passing.

Also change:

```
baseurl + 'registro'
```

for:

```
baseurl + '/registro'
```